# Error with Entity Framework 4 and MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a database with 3 tables:

- Subjects
- Members
- Topics

Then I added the connection string to `web.config` and created an EF with the following classes:

```
namespace MySite.Models
{
    public class MySiteDBModel : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TopicDataModel> TopicDataModel { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
        {
            mb.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            
        }
    }

    public class Topic
    {
        [Key]
        public int TopicID { get; set; }
        public int SubID { get; set; }
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string TDate { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int Displays { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TopicView> TopicView { get; set; }
    }
    public class Subject
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubID { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topic { get; set; }
    }

    public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string FLName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topic { get; set; }
    }

    public class TopicDataModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int TopicID { get; set; }
        public string SubName { get; set; }
        public string FLName { get; set; }
        public string TDate { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Displays { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now when I am trying to query the database with the this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var topics = from t in db.Topics
                         join s in db.Subjects on t.SubID equals s.SubID
                         join m in db.Members on t.MemberID equals m.MemberID
                         select new TopicDataModel()
                         {
                             TopicID = t.TopicID,
                             SubName = s.SubName,
                             FLName = m.FLName,
                             TDate = t.TDate,
                             Title = t.Title,
                             Displays = t.Displays,
                             Description = t.Description
                         };
            return View(topics.ToList());
        }
```

I got this Error:

> The model backing the 'MySiteDBModel' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or
>   call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance.
>   For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will
>   automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it
>   with new data.

Please help me!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some controls on how EF is handling changes to your data model. Julie Lerman has a good blog post on [Turning Off Code First Database Initialization Completely](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/turning-off-code-first-database-initialization-completely/).

Also, here is a good overview - [Inside Code First Database Initialization](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/)